# How do I correctly use report-level filters in Power BI?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am fairly new to Power BI and working on my first project. I currently have two separate sql views setup and connected to my project as well as a simple visual for each one. They both share a common field that I want to filter on, call it customer_key. I tried adding a filter to the "Filters on all pages" section but it doesn't seem to filter both visuals, only the one I dragged the field from. I ultimately want to do the same thing with a date field so that this report can be easily re-ran for any of our customers and any date range. Suggestions?

I would like to have a single filter that affects all data sets in my report, provided they have that column to filter on. Currently, I am using separate filters for each data set (even though I moved the filter to the "Filters on all pages" section).

Comment: If you're new to StackOverflow, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the "common" customer_key columns are not related. So you have to set up a relation between your two sql views. However, if both are fact tables this is not straight forward, since you would end up with a many-to-many relation.

Workaround: Extract the unique customer_key values from both views and create a third dim table from it. Now you can create two one-to-many relations to your sql views and use the third table customer_key as a report-level filter.

You can create the connecting dim table with the following DAX table expression:

```
Table3 = 
DISTINCT(
    UNION(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            'Table1',
            "customer_key", 'Table1'[customer_key]
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            'Table2',
            "customer_key", 'Table2'[customer_key]
        )
    )
)
```